# Selenium Fetching Values In Changing HTML values

Tags: python, selenium

I want to scrape a website where a bunch of `<li>` are changed in mere seconds how do I do this without having to refresh the page?

I'm trying to scrape: https://www.betburger.com/arbs as you can see the values on the %'s are changing so fast. I want to get those values in the shortest time as possible.

Here's the code im using:

```
arbs_url = 'https://www.betburger.com/arbs'
browser.get(arbs_url)

time.sleep(10)

while True:


    scroller = browser.find_element_by_class_name("scroller")
    arbs = scroller.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")

    for arb in arbs:
        arb_percent = arb.get_attribute("innerText")
        arb_percent = arb_percent.split('%')[0]
        print(arb_percent)
```

I think the site is using server side processing as the HTML just changes, my code works in scraping but the values within it doesn't change. Is there a way to do this with selenium? because making another `browser.get()` would lengthen the loading time for the scraper.

Answer (score 0):

Confused by what you mean "in mere seconds", if the time is consistent you could just wait for X amount of seconds and then retrieve the values once they've been changed. Also you could take the approach of waiting for the value to change.

Comment: does this mean that I have to broswer.get again the url? this will refresh the page right? the values are just chaing within a section and so is the html. If possible I dont want to request again. I want to get the values as they change. My current code isnt able to do that because it only takes the first values and not the next set of values that appears on the section

Answer (score 0):

Induce `WebDriverWait` and `visibility_of_all_elements_located`() and use the following css selector.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver

browser=webdriver.Chrome()
arbs_url = 'https://www.betburger.com/arbs'
browser.get(arbs_url)

arbs=WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#arbsScroll>.scroller li")))

for arb in arbs:
    arb_percent = arb.get_attribute("innerText")
    arb_percent = arb_percent.split('%')[0]
    print(arb_percent)
```

Comment: I'm getting a TimeoutException, the idea is great that it waits until all elements are present but I think this will be ineffective when those values change